# How to clear hadoop fifo queue?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I have set up a pseudo distributed mode cluster setup. The FIFO scheduler got stuck somehow in between and therefore a lot of jobs got piled up which I had scheduler through cron. Now, when I restarted YARN resourcemanager it gets stuck after a while and the jobs keep piling up.

Is there a way I can clear the whole queue. Or, is it that my complete understanding of hadoop scheduling is somewhere flawed. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to kill all the jobs in your queue, you can use this shell script:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop job -list | awk ' { system("$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop job -kill " $1) } '
```

Comment: Also, if you're having trouble with jobs piling up, I'd suggest writing a quick script that you can call through a cron job that checks the size of the job queue (via `hadoop job -list`, maybe piped into `wc` or something) and stops new jobs from being created if too many jobs have built up. If you really want to get fancy, you could even write the incoming jobs to a temp file and have your cron job retry them once the queue clears.